# Forbidden You don't have permission to access on searching a special character

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, special-characters, http-status-code-403

I am supporting a java application which has a search bar which matches the keywords and gets the results from the cache.

The application runs in Tomcat and has a Apache web server too.

There is an issue while searching **aaa'** the special character ***'*** is causing the problem and i get to

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /xx/xx/xxxx.jsp

The search is fine in local setup with the abscence of Web Server. As i saw some posts suggesting the issue could be caused by Web server config.

What are the possibilities?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nagaraja JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not an issue it is a secutity constraint by the apache web server or FireWall rule to protect from cross site sctipting or sql injection using %27 (single quote). **I used POST method instead of using GET** method to send request. That is the solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Apache web-server's security configuration must be causing this. Look into the web server logs, you will find rule code/name which is triggered because of these sequence of characters. 
Disabling rule is one of the options to make this work but not always a good idea.

Comment: 10.129.239.197 - nagaraja.jb-ext@aaa.com [20/Feb/2017:06:33:43 -0500] "POST /vb/dwr/call/plaincall/__System.pageLoaded.dwr HTTP/1.1" 200 156
10.129.239.197 - - [20/Feb/2017:06:33:52 -0500] "GET /vb/pages/searchResult.jsp?searchTerm=aaa%27&searchTermForDoc= HTTP/1.1" 403 199



This is what i see in the Web Server log. How can i disable the rule? And is it ok to do so?

Comment: Well if you can disable a rule, as I said it depends on your corporate security policy. If you can make changes in your data then you don't have to. I don't see any rule violation number in your comment. I am not sure what rule is being triggered from your log statements.